# Shiny w/ ggplot produces erroneous legend: duplicate legend entries with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to plot a facet plot with added geom_hline and show the line in the legend. However, when I add the line to the legend, all entries duplicate to the number of facets.
How can I avoid this behaviour?
Here is my MWE

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

df <- mpg

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        plotlyOutput('graph')
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$graph <- renderPlotly({
        p <- ggplot2::mpg %>%
        plot_ly %>%
        ggplot() +
        geom_point(aes(displ, hwy, color = class))

        facet <- p + facet_wrap(~year)

        facet + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 20, linetype = 'hline20'), color = '#00b700') +
            scale_linetype_manual(name = 'line', values = 1,
                                 guide = guide_legend(aes = list(color = "#00b700")))
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `shiny` nor `ggplot2`. The problem is the conversion of a `ggplot2` object into a `plotly` object.

Below I've isolated the ggplot steps from the plotly step and completely removed shiny from the picture.

```
p <- ggplot2::mpg %>%
      ggplot() +
      geom_point(aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class))

facet <- p + facet_wrap(~year)

final <- facet + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 20, linetype = 'hline20'), color = '#00b700') +
    scale_linetype_manual(name = 'line', values = 1, guide = guide_legend(aes = list(color = "#00b700")))

print(final)
```

The above displays fine.

```
ggplotly(final)
```

This above has the same display errors as yours, without involving shiny.

Legend issues and other display issues are common when converting ggplot2 objects to plotly objects. Plotly and ggplot2 are completely independent plotting frameworks with their own syntax and graphics objects. Plotly provides conversion function methods but things still get lost in translation from one format to the other, because there is not a complete equivalency between them.

I'd recommend trying to implement your plot in native `plotly` syntax instead of trying to convert it from `ggplot2`.

Comment: On an additional note, I just spotted that you have two variables attached to `color`. The `class` from your data and the hard-coded color for the `geom_hline()`. 

`ggplot2` can handle it because it has different glyphs for points and lines. Plotly doesn't, so what it does instead is combine all the sources of color encoding into tuples. So you get all the combinations of class and that weird definition of linetype color you tried to setup.

Comment: If you remove the hard-coded line aesthetics (hard-coded values don't belong in aesthetics), as I've done below, plotly can convert the object just fine

    `mpg %>% ggplot() +
        geom_point(aes(displ, hwy, color = class)) +
        facet_wrap(~year) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 20, linetype = 2, color = '#00b700')`